# Where do I put images in the eclipse resource folder?

Tags: android, eclipse

Under 'res' there are several folders, from drawable-ldpi to drawable-xxhdpi, where should I put my images if I just want it to be the same image on all devices?

Comment: However you can create a general folder named 'drawable' and put your regular images there

Comment: Put them all in the `drawable-nodpi` folder. That is if you don't want the images to be scaled by Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may put it under either of the folder regardless of its dpi:

- res/drawable-nodpi
- res/drawable

Comment: Neither of those folders exist, should I create them under 'res'?

Comment: Yes, if the folder(s) don't exist, simply create them, and dont forget to **`clean+refresh`** your project after this

Answer (score 2):

You have to put it in drawable-nodpi. The drawables in drawable-nodpi don't get scaled based on the density of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in `res/drawable`. If Android doesn't find the resource in the other folders it will defualt there.